# Flutter how get local download folder with path_provider

Tags: flutter, directory, download, local-files

At the moment i build a chat similar in wahtsapp.
I would like upload some local files (pdf, txt, image...).

Like this:

[image]

I try to get the local files via path_provider.
But i dont get access to download folder.

My problem:
I don't know how i can access the dowload folder with path_provider.

See my code:

```
//load local files from download folder
_loadLocalFile() async {
  //absoulute path to download file 
  var file = io.Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download/')
      .listSync(); //use your folder name insted of resume.
  //console output -> []

  //other try to get download folder 
  List<io.Directory>? documents = await getExternalStorageDirectories();
//console output -> [Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/de.securebuy.securebuy/files', Directory: '/storage/1BEC-0908/Android/data/de.securebuy.securebuy/files']

  print(documents.toString());
}
```

I also add to AndroidManifest following rules:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
```

Anyone have a idea how i can build a function similar in image?
Is that possible?

Many thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

till now , `pathprovider` isn't going to let you in downloads file , so if you are on android you can just write the downloads directory , else using `android_path_provider` it is a null-safety package and you can accsess it via :`var downloadsPath = await AndroidPathProvider.downloadsPath;` , on ios you can get only the app directory cuase ios makes it's own file for every app thus we use 'pathprovider' with `Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`

**Update :**
i see what you are trying to achieve and this is not what `pathprovider` pcakage is used for , you have to use `file_picker` , read thier docs , i thinks that this is what you need

Comment: Hello @Fahmi, i updated my question. Pls look at them.
Many thx.

Comment: @Zogger updated answer

Comment: I've heard of the package before. But this is not a offical package from flutter and i'm would programming a high security app.
Did you now is this package secure? Many thx

Comment: @Zogger it should be ! there is no way to do this on flutter without this package or by doing it on native channels , the package has a 1.5+ likes and has passed all the pub tests so you should be able to consider it  a secure package